# Create a range of dates

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, foundation

I want to create a array of range which contains days betweens a specific start and end date.

For example, I have a start date with 1 January 2012 and and an end date with 7 January 2012. The array or range should contain a collection of NSDate objects (7 in total).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NSCalendar is helpful here, since it knows the calendar related to the dates.   So, by using the following (assuming you have startDate and endData and that you want to include both in the list), you can iterate through the dates, adding a single day (NSCalendar will take care of wrapping the months and leap year, etc).

```
NSMutableArray *dateList = [NSMutableArray array];
NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:1];

[dateList addObject: startDate];
NSDate *currentDate = startDate;
// add one the first time through, so that we can use NSOrderedAscending (prevents millisecond infinite loop)
currentDate = [currentCalendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
while ( [endDate compare: currentDate] != NSOrderedAscending) {
    [dateList addObject: currentDate];
    currentDate = [currentCalendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
}

[comps release];
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I was looking for. However the condition in the while loop alway returns true.

`(lldb) po endDate`
`(NSDate *) $6 = 0x06b9cc60 2012-03-11 00:12:42 +0000`
`(lldb) po currentDate`
`(NSDate *) $7 = 0x06b9dd20 2012-03-11 00:12:42 +0000`

But the return value still is true.

Comment: I'm guessing you ran this with startDate=[NSDate date] and endDate=[NSDate date], which result in two dates that are not identical, but are very similar (off by a few milliseconds).   I've modified this so that it's safe for this condition, although if you're using a date picker, it probably won't be a problem, as the dates will be manually set at 00:00:00.0, not 00:12:42.xx and 00:12:42.yy

Comment: This works great, but I ran into a problem where I was missing the end date in November.  Turned out to be daylight savings time.  Add this to your NSCalendar declaration to avoid that `[currentCalendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]]; // ignore daylight savings`

Answer (score 1):

Just create them and add them to an array...

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[comps setMonth:1];
[comps setYear:2012];

for(int i=1;i<=7;i++) {
    [comps setDay:i];
    [arr addObject:[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Apple doc: 
To compute a sequence of dates, use the enumerateDatesStartingAfterDate:matchingComponents:options:usingBlock: method instead of calling this method (
- nextDateAfterDate:matchingComponents:options:
) in a loop with the previous loop iteration's result.

As I got, it will iterate all dates that matched with "matchingComponents" till you finish iteration with "stop.memory = true"

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let startDate = calendar.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
let finishDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 10, toDate: startDate, options: [])
let dayComponent = NSDateComponents()
dayComponent.hour = 1

calendar.enumerateDatesStartingAfterDate(startDate, matchingComponents: dayComponent, options: [.MatchStrictly]) { (date, exactMatch, stop) in
    print(date)
    if date!.compare(finishDate!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {
        // .memory gets at the value of an UnsafeMutablePointer
        stop.memory = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Please do not **just** post a code block as an answer but also give a little explanation to improve the quality of your answer.